# FileSize through javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, upload

I want to check the file size of the file selected by user, at the client side by using javascript.The code i am using for this is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var myFile = document.getElementById('myfile');

  //binds to onchange event of the input field
  myFile.addEventListener('change', function() {
  //this.files[0].size gets the size of your file.
   alert(this.files[0].size);

   });
 </script>
```

But when i run the code, choose a file, nothing happpens. 
Any body tell me what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Your code works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/Z3CLu/)  (in HTML5 browsers with the File API). Make sure that your `<script>` block is **after** the `<input>` element. In that jsfiddle, it's in the "load" handler.

Comment: or in `window.onload=function { ... }`

Comment: @mplungjan yes I updated the answer a little bit; I got the "onload" for free via jsfiddle :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the file size using javascript.  Security in the browser prevents file system access by Javascript.  You'd need to use Flash, or ActiveX or something that would be able to be granted permissions to do this I believe.

EDIT: If you are using the HTML5 File API then I guess you can do this - but as you've not indicated that anywhere I didn't assume that this was the case.  I will put HTML as a tag on your post.

Comment: He's trying to use the HTML 5 file API I think.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me using jquery:

http://jsfiddle.net/UUdcy/

```
$('#myfile').change( function() {
    var fileInput = $("#myfile")[0];
    var imgbytes = fileInput.files[0].fileSize; // Size returned in bytes.
    $('body').append('<p>'+imgbytes+'</p>');
});​
```